# Lua lrex lib pcre pattern matching

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, user-agent

I am using Lua lrex lib (PCRE) to regex pattern matching and trying with following code.

```
local string="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
local pattern=[[(Chrome|Chromieum)/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?(\d*)]]

for w in rex.gmatch( string, pattern) do
    ngx.say(w)
end
```

It should display Chrome 39.0.2171
but its only displaying Chrome in output.

Can anyone help me to correct this error. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: `local pattern=[[(Chrome|Chromium)/(\d|\.)+]]`

Answer (score 1):

You get multiple values, but only the first one is captured in `w`, so you either need to add more values to the `for` loop or add another grouping that captures the entire results you need by adding another set of brackets: `[[((Chrome|Chromieum)/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?(\d*))]]`.

Comment: if I add more OR into pattern like Chrome|Chromiem|Safari it search the the string and return me result with Chrome and Safari.
But the issue is with digit . it does not return me version no as i mentioned like /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?(\d*)). How to overcome with this issue. How i can get the whole result using single pattern.